# Can't create a table called State in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I want to save a list of States in my database. But it seems I can't call it 'State'. Intellisense in SQL Management Studio colors it differently.

Is this a correct assumption and I should call it something else?

```
create table Category
(
    ID int primary key identity(1,1),
    Name nvarchar(256) not null
)

go

create table Subcategory
(
    ID int primary key identity(1,1),
    Name nvarchar(256) not null,
    IDCategory int foreign key references Category(ID)
)

go

create table Advert
(
    ID int primary key identity(1,1),
    IDAdvertiser int foreign key references Advertiser(ID),
    IDSubcategory int foreign key references Subcategory(ID),
    ImagePath nvarchar(2048) not null,
    StartDate datetime not null,
    FinishDate datetime
)

go

create table Advertiser
(
    ID int primary key identity(1,1),
    Name nvarchar(2048) not null,
    Contact nvarchar(256) not null,
    Website nvarchar(256) not null
)

go

create table State
```

Comment: State is too generic/common - make it more informational.  IE state of what?  Then you don't conflict with reserved words, *and* it's more obvious to others reading your data model.

Comment: I agree with OMG Ponies. Table names should be intuitive. Tbl names should give a hint to the data it contains.

Comment: Why not USAState? Other countries don't have them and you can't assume if you want to go outside of the US of A. See [this comment chain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3637935/column-type-and-size-for-international-country-subdivisions-states-provinces-t/3638587#3638587)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Call it [State] to avoid conflicting with system reserved words. Though in most cases, that is not neccessary, the parser is usually smart enough to know when you are referencing a table name.

Answer (score 2):

don't rely on intellisense to tell you what's correct. a table named `State` is fine. But when in doubt, surround in `[]`, like `[State]`.

Answer (score 0):

Most of our tables follow a slightly different naming scheme.

For example, instead of "State" which indicates a single item we call it "States".  Instead of "Advertiser" (same thing) we use "Advertisers"

Comment: I name them singularly because I like letting Entity Framework pluralize the collections it generates.

Comment: I agree. Also, I use Progress 4GL for one of our products at work. The query syntax is "FOR EACH [table-name] WHERE...". It sounds better saying "FOR EACH State" than "FOR EACH States".

Comment: Yeah, I figured this was a preference thing driven in part by any ORM or other tool involved.

Comment: Convention on naming table - at least "academically", says table names must be in plural form. But then that depends on many other factors.